# The copy-symbol function

Tags: copy, common-lisp, symbols

Common Lisp provides a number of functions for copying objects; namely, `copy-list`, `copy-alist`, `copy-seq`, `copy-structure`, `copy-tree`, and `copy-symbol`. However, `copy-symbol` seems to operate somewhat differently than the others. All the others (most notably `copy-structure`) succeed with a general pattern like:

```
(setq riddle "gifted magician")  ;set some value for Tom Riddle
"gifted magician"
(setf (get 'riddle :school) "Hogwarts")  ;install a property for him
"Hogwarts"
(setq voldemort (copy-symbol 'riddle t))  ;attempt to clone him
#:RIDDLE
(get 'voldemort :school)  ;failed magic
NIL
```

1. Can I give voldemort everything riddle has (except his `symbol-name`) at once, or is it necessary to copy over `symbol-value`, `symbol-plist`, `symbol-package`, and  `symbol-function` from riddle separately? (The [HyperSpec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_sym.htm) gives examples of use, but they do not deal with `intern`ing the copied symbol under a new name.)
2. What is `copy-symbol` normally used for (and what else could it perhaps be used for)?

Comment: voldemort is not the new symbol. It is a variable, where the new symbol is set to...

Comment: So, can we say the important distinctions to keep in mind are between a representation, what that representation represents, and the linguistic entity we use to refer to the representation?  In this case, the lisp symbol object voldemort, being interned, is a representation (residing in memory) that represents (or refers to) another lisp symbol object (namely, #:RIDDLE, uninterned).

Comment: We also _use_ the name of a symbol (eg, "VOLDEMORT") as a linguistic variable to refer to the symbol itself. Likewise, we use the linguistic name "#:RIDDLE" to refer to the uninterned symbol #:RIDDLE. The difference is that "VOLDEMORT", being interned, is a lisp string object in its own right (the symbol's `symbol-name`), while "#:RIDDLE" is purely linguistic, and cannot be used as a variable. Critique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(setf (get symbol key) new-value)` sets a property on a symbol object. Thus every place the symbol `riddle` is used it is the same symbol and thus it will have the same property list. The property list is used for implementation aspects of the language and it is not a way to make objects. Early lisps used it to store global functions, global value, global macro. Moderns lisps us it very little, but it stays for backward compatibility.

```
(setq riddle "gifted magician")
```

This updates an already existing variable `riddle` to be asociated with the string "gifted magician"

```
(setf (get 'riddle :school) "Hogwarts")
```

This has nothing to do with the variable `riddle` (the string "gifted magician") but you make a property on the global symbol `riddle`. CL uses property lists to store debug information and early lisps used it as the global scope. It's not a way to create an object.

```
(setq voldemort (copy-symbol 'riddle t))
```

This makes a copy of the symbol `riddle` with the property list and the symbolic value is associated with `voldemort`, thus:

```
voldemort               ; ==> riddle (looks the same, but is a copy)
(eq voldemort 'riddle)  ; ==> nil
(get voldemort :school) ; ==> "Hogwarts"
```

Here is how to do this with [classes and objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/m_defcla.htm#defclass):

```
(defclass magician ()
  ((name        :initarg :name)
   (description :initarg :description :initform "")
   (school      :initarg :school :initform nil)))

(defparameter *riddle* 
  (make-instance 'magician :name        "Tom Riddle" 
                           :description "gifted magician")

(setf (slot-value *riddle* 'school) "Hogwarts")

; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067899/is-there-a-generic-method-for-cloning-clos-objects
(defparameter *voldemort* (shallow-copy-object *riddle*))
(slot-value *voldemort* 'school)              ; ==> "Hogwarts"
(setf (slot-value *riddle* 'school) "Other")
(slot-value *voldemort* 'school)              ; ==> "Hogwarts"
(slot-value *riddle* 'school)                 ; ==> "Other"
```

How to do it with [structures](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/m_defstr.htm):

*Structures does more behind the scene, like make accessors and constructors, but they are less flexible than CLOS classes and they only have single inheritance. In the example it will almost work the same.*

```
(defstruct magician name (description "") (school nil))

(defparameter *riddle* (make-magician :name "Tom Riddle" 
                                      :description "Gifted magician"))
(setf (magician-school *riddle*) "Hogwarts")

(defparameter *voldemort* (copy-structure *riddle*))

(magician-school *voldemort*)              ; ==> "Hogwarts"
(setf (magician-school *riddle*) "Other")
(magician-school *voldemort*)              ; ==> "Hogwarts"
(magician-school *riddle*)                 ; ==> "Other"
```

Comment: Looks like you can transfer all slots at once with class instances, but only individually with structures. Can you suggest any circumstances when you might want to use `copy-symbol`? (ps: assuming you intended to say the value of voldemort is #:riddle (rather than riddle), since that's why they are not `eq`?)

Comment: @davypough Note that adding to a symbols plist has little to do with structures. I've added how to do it with structures. the `#:` in front of the name indicates that it's uninterned. Only one symbol with the string name `"riddle"` can be interned so a copy that is not eq has to be uninterned. Two different copies would both be `#:riddle` but will not be `eq`. There are no reason to use `copy-symbol` that I can think of. When making macros one needs uninterned symbols but `gensym` is far better at making them in such a way that you can differ between each invocation.