# Using a quoted list of slots for Peter Seibel's defclass macro

Tags: common-lisp

I am using the defclass macro from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-parsing-binary-files.html), which takes as argument a list of symbols.

I would like to change the macro in order to let it accept a quoted list of symbols. This has the benefit of having thenm defined as constants that can be used in other convenience functions, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902139/2336738). I confused myself in trying to get this done.

My use case is following:

```
(defconstant state-slots '(unit motion mode moc-offset woc-pos woc-inc feed spindle))

;; would like to use the quoted list here:
(defclass-by-slots gc-state (unit       ; :mm(=G21) :inch(=G20)
                             motor      ; nil :on 
                             motion     ; :jog(=G0) :lin(=G1) :cw(=G2) :ccw(=G3)        
                             mode       ; :abs(=G90) :inc(=G91)
                             moc-offset ; woc-zero(xyz, mm) from moc-zero
                             woc-pos    ; woc-pos(xyz, mm) from woc-zero
                             woc-inc    
                             feed
                             spindle))

;; can use quoted slot list when using a convenience function, e.g:
(defun format-by-slots (o slots &optional str-type)
  (let* ((f (lambda (s$) (eval (format-slot o s$))))
         (str-type (string-upcase str-type))
         (r (concatenate
             'string
             (format nil "~A (~A)" o (class-of o))
             (reduce (lambda (s1 s2) (concatenate 'string s1 s2))
                     (loop for s in slots
                           when (funcall f s) collect it)
                     :from-end t :initial-value (format nil "~%")))))
    (if str-type
        (ppcre:regex-replace-all
         (format nil "^#<~A \\{(\\d|[A-F])+\\}> " str-type) 
         r
         (format nil "#<~A {...}> " str-type))
        r)))
```

I am using this for several classes defined by different slots.

The nuisance is that I cannot have defined the slots uniformly for the type definition and the convenience functions which is source of annoying errors.

Solution based on [Rainer Joswig's answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154538/2336738):

```
(defmacro def-my-class (name supers slots-symbol)
  "The value of a symbol of slots-symbol is used as the
  list of slots."
  `(defclass ,name ,supers
     ,(if (and (symbolp slots-symbol)
               (symbol-value slots-symbol)
               (listp (symbol-value slots-symbol)))
          (mapcar #'slot->defclass-slot (symbol-value slots-symbol))
          (error "~a is not a symbol which names a list of slot names" slots-symbol))))
```

Comment: probably good to give an actual example of what you want to achieve

Comment: I added a use case.

Answer (score 1):

**Symbol values at compile time**

If you want to use the value of a symbol at compile time, then you need to make sure that it is defined. Two usual ways to do that:

- define the symbol in a file and load it before compiling another file where it is used
- use `EVAL-WHEN` to execute a symbol definition (`defvar`, `defparameter,`defconstant` ...) at compile time

**Read-time evaluation**

One possibility to use a symbol value during compilation is to use read-time evaluation. You would need to make sure that the constant value of `+state-slots+` is defined during compilation:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defconstant +state-slots+
    '(unit motion mode moc-offset woc-pos woc-inc feed spindle)))

(defclass foo ()
  #.+state-slots+)
```

**Custom Macro**

If the value of `+state-slots+` is defined at compile time, then we can also use it in a macro:

```
(defmacro def-my-class (name supers slots-symbol)
  "The value of a symbol of slots-symbol is used as the
  list of slots."
  `(defclass ,name ,supers
     ,(if (and (symbolp slots-symbol)
               (symbol-value slots-symbol)
               (listp (symbol-value slots-symbol)))
          (symbol-value slots-symbol)
        (error "~a is not a symbol which names a list of slot names"))))

(def-my-class foo () +state-slots+)
```

Comment: Excellent - combined with the slot conversion as cited above, the class definition can be enhanced with standard accessors (added above as I could not paste it here).